# Grant sysadmin permissions to 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting

For SQL Server 2012 and above, as [What's New in SQL Server Installation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500459%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) states:

> **BUILTIN\administrators** and **Local System** (**NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**) are not automatically provisioned in the sysadmin fixed server role.

In my case this has become a problem: I have a WiX installer which uses a `Custom Action` C++ code to setup database data (create the database, views, procedures, data etc.). `Custom Action` runs as user `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, but this account does not have permission to execute `CREATE DATABASE` scripts.

1. Is it correct to give `sysadmin` role to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` while installing software? Or maybe there is a better solution?
2. If it is correct, is it possible to find the proper user name for `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? I need this name in order to change permissions*. In different locales this name is different, for example, `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or `NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА`.

---

Adding `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` to the `sysadmin` role:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT name
    FROM master.sys.server_principals 
    WHERE IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin', name) = 1 
    AND name LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
)
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember
    @loginame = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```

Searching `sys.server_principals` for `name LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY\%'` will not work because sometimes there will be more than one `NT AUTHORITY\...` user. I encountered a case like that on one of my virtual machines.

Comment: Rather than granting sa privileges what you can do is find out what WiX installer needs to do and for that what permissions are needed. Grant those and you should be good to go. To start with you can grant dbcreator server role, install. If it errors out with permissions errors then grant again whatever is necessary. The other option is grant 'sa' rights temporarily, do your install and once done revoke the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the name of [well-known security identifiers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) (SIDs) using a PowerShell script:

```ps
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-5-18")
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
```

Personally I never had to do this from C/C++ code. See the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx) about the WINAPI or `System.Security` namespace for managed code.

There is a compact example in the Stack Overflow Q & A [WinAPI LookupAccountSid from an .evt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403261) by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau):

```cpp
static const DWORD MAX_BUFF_SIZE = 256;

wstring userNameFromSid(SID userSid, wstring computerName)
{
    wchar_t buffName[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffNameSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    wchar_t buffDomain[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffDomainSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    SID_NAME_USE SidType;

    if (LookupAccountSid(!computerName.empty() ? computerName.c_str() : NULL, &userSid, buffName, &buffNameSize, buffDomain, &buffDomainSize, &SidType))
    {
        return buffName;
    }

    /*Here some code to print error in a Message box*/
    return L"";
}
```

Is there any problem placing `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` in the SQL Server `sysadmin` role when installing software from a reliable source? There should be no problem, I hope, but who knows...

Comment: If you're going to make obscure configuration changes like this at install time: I would strongly advise you to inform the user that you are making those changes. -- Additionally, I would consider rolling back those changes when the installer completes, so as to leave their machine in a pristine state.